# Monitoring websites on the Web

Tags: discovery, sharing

I have witnessed that less people are using RSS technology for monitoring a multitude of websites. Rather, more people seem to be using social media products such as Twitter, which equally share links to content the user is interested in. Others might just keep a collection of bookmarks for frequent revisits, and some will only visit websites they remember off the top of their head.

I am interested in finding statistics that supports this. I know that people tend to follow a multitude of all sorts of content on the Web, but are there statistics to prove this? How are people staying up-to-date nowadays? Even better, are there statistics to prove what facilities people use for this purpose?

If you know of any studies, please share!

Answer (score 1):

My interests are ever evolving.  RSS, Podcasts, News aggregators, meh.  There is only time for only so much information.  It is hard with those distractions to get anything done if they are part of the 'regular schedule'.

Outside of a select few on twitter, I don't 'follow' particular sites with regularity over a long term anymore.  Occassionally things get forwarded to personal email archives, cited in a digital notebook for potential future research, or possibly bookmarked or link only forwarded to personal email for near term reading or reference.

For statistics and trends on specific sites, [alexa](http://alexa.com) is probably a good place to start.